# Where does Powershell ISE store tabs when it crashes?

Tags: windows, powershell, crash, powershell-ise

My Powershell ISE is crashing upon being launched; and I believe it is due to a tab/file that is being loaded when ISE returns from being exited incorrectly. As a result, I'm currently unable to launch ISE.. I'm looking for the file/location where Powershell ISE stores the tabs/files that are currently opened so that I can delete it and make it start without loading anything. I am able to start it as another user with no issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx), I've found that the ISE stores and loads its recovered files from:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft_Corporation\powershell_ise.exe_StrongName_lw2v2vm3wmtzzpebq33gybmeoxukb04w\3.0.0.0\AutoSaveFiles
```

Holds true for both Windows 7 with PS 3.0, Windows 8.1 with PS 4.0 and Windows 10 with PS 5.1

Answer (score 6):

This will always give you the correct path:

```
(Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft_Corporation\powershell_ise*").Path
```

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly different for lower versions but you can still get there with [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28974651/1501497)' location.

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft_Corporation\powershell_ise.exe_StrongName_lw2v2vm3wmtzzpebq33gybmeoxukb04w`

Should get you to the parent folder every time, regardless of the version.

Note: I was going to add this as a comment but I can't yet...